# relationship between exports and requirejs

Tags: requirejs

From my understanding, exports is only for nodejs, because I'ven seen it in node. Requirejs is only used at browser side. 
Is this correct?

What is the relationship among require.js, exports?

Answer (score 0):

Node.js modules are defined according to the CommonJS format. RequireJS allows you to wrap modules defined in a CommonJS format in callback passed to `define`. This Node.js module:

```
var foo = require("./foo");

function bar(whatever) {
    foo(whatever+1);
}

exports.bar = bar;
```

could be used with RequireJS as:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    var foo = require("./foo");

    function bar(whatever) {
        foo(whatever+1);
    }

    exports.bar = bar;
});
```

This support is documented [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html).

RequireJS' "native" format of declaring modules is the AMD format. In this format you do not use `exports` but instead have the factory function you pass to `define` return the object you want to export:

```
define(["./foo"], function(foo) {
    function bar(whatever) {
        foo(whatever+1);
    }

    return { bar: bar };
});
```

Comment: In nodejs, return {bar; bar} still works, right? Why they invent exports in nodejs? Why no exports in AMD format?

Comment: I've just tried using `return` to export something in Node, and just as I suspected, it does not work. The reason Node.js works the way it does is because the devs decided to settle on the CommonJS format. Why they decided to use CommonJS, I don't know.